# SQL Server loop through a table for every 5 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to write a stored procedure or table function to return a new data table as a new data source.
I wish to loop through the original table for every 5 rows base on the invoice ID column (it's possible not start from 1), the first 5 rows add to the left of the new table and the second 5 rows add to the right of the new table, the third 5 rows to the left and so on.

For example, Here is the original table:
[image: Original Table]

Here is the expect table:
[image: Result table]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about `11` and `12` row?

Comment: its weird, please suggest what are your requirement for this and give your effort too

Comment: @D-Shih Hey D-Shih, 11-15 on the left, 16-20 on the right and so on...

Comment: Ideally, do such *presentation* work in a UI/report builder, not down in the database. Despite superficial resemblances, tables/result sets are not the same as spreadsheets.

Comment: I agree - this is a presentation exercise and should not be done in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @rowCount int = 5;
with cte as (
    select *,( (IN_InvoiceID-1) / @rowCount ) % 2 group1
        ,( (IN_InvoiceID-1) / @rowCount ) group2
        ,IN_InvoiceID % @rowCount group3
    from T 
)
select * from cte
select T1.INID,T1.IN_InvoiceID,T1.IN_InvoiceAmount,T2.INID,T2.IN_InvoiceID,T2.IN_InvoiceAmount
from CTE  T1
left join CTE T2 on T2.group1 = 1 and T1.group2 = T2.group2-1 and T1.group3 = T2.group3
where T1.group1 = 0
```

---

#### Test DDL

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([INID] varchar(38), [IN_InvoiceID] int, [IN_InvoiceAmount] int)
;

INSERT INTO T
    ([INID], [IN_InvoiceID], [IN_InvoiceAmount])
VALUES
    ('DB3E17E6-35C5-41:121-93B1-F809BF6B2972', 1, 2999),
    ('3212F048-8213-4FCC-AB64-121485B77D4E43', 2, 3737),
    ('E3526373-A204-40F5-801C-7F8302A4E5E2', 3, 3175),
    ('76CC9C19-BF79-4E8A-8034-A33805AD3390', 4, 391),
    ('EC7A2FBC-B62D-4865-88DE-A8097975F125', 5, 1206),
    ('52AD3046-21331-4F0A-BD1D-67F232C54244', 6, 402),
    ('CA48F132-A9F5-4516-9E58-CDEE6644AAD1', 7, 1996),
    ('02E10C31-CAB2-4220-B66A-CEE5E67A9378', 8, 3906),
    ('98F1EEFF-B07A-4B65-87F4-E165264284DD', 9, 2575),
    ('91EBDD8B-B73C-470C-8900-DD66078483DB', 10, 2965),
    ('6E2490E5-C4DE-4833-877F-1590F7BDC1B8', 11, 1603),
    ('00985921-AC3C-4E3E-BAE1-7F58302F831A', 12, 1302)
;
```

### Result:

[image: 2018-12-10.16.19.53-image.png]

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check article [Display Data in Multiple Columns using SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/display-data-in-multiple-columns-in-sql.aspx) showing with example case how a database developer can show the list of data rows in a columnar mode using Row_Number() function and mode arithmetic expression

[image]

You need to add additional columns from the same row that is different in the sample

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you want to split the table into 2 tables with alternating 5 rows. An easy way to do this would be:

1. Take data into a temp table having an extra column (lets say
   grouping_id)
2. Update the grouping id so that each 5 rows have the same id. You can
   use `in_invoiceId % 5` (the nod function). After this step the first 5
   rows will have grouping_id 0, next 5 will have 1, next will have 2
   (assuming your invoice id is incremented +1 for all rows).
3. You can just do a normal select with where clause for odd and even grouping_id

Answer (score 0):

You may try with the following approach. Dividing the table is done with `(((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IN_InvoiceID) - 1) / 5) % 2 = 0)` which groups records in left and right groups.

```
CREATE TABLE #InvoiceTable(
    IN_ID varchar(24),
    IN_InvoiceID int
)


INSERT INTO #InvoiceTable (IN_ID, IN_InvoiceID)
VALUES
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-1DDF', 1),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-3DDF', 2),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-4DDF', 3),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-5DDF', 4),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-6DDF', 5),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-7DDF', 6),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-aDDF', 7),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-sDDF', 8),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-dDDF', 9),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-dDDF', 10),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-dDDF', 11),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-dDDF', 12);

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        IN_ID, 
        IN_InvoiceID, 
        CASE
            WHEN (((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IN_InvoiceID) - 1) / 5) % 2 = 0) THEN 'L'
            ELSE 'R'
        END AS IN_Position
    FROM #InvoiceTable
),
cteL AS (
    SELECT IN_ID, IN_InvoiceID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IN_InvoiceID) AS IN_RowNumber
    FROM cte
    WHERE IN_Position = 'L'
),
cteR AS (
    SELECT IN_ID, IN_InvoiceID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IN_InvoiceID) AS IN_RowNumber
    FROM cte
    WHERE IN_Position = 'R'
)

SELECT cteL.IN_ID, cteL.IN_InvoiceID, cteR.IN_ID, cteR.IN_InvoiceID
FROM cteL
LEFT JOIN cteR ON (cteL.IN_RowNumber = cteR.IN_RowNumber)
```

Output:

```
IN_ID               IN_InvoiceID    IN_ID               IN_InvoiceID
2345-BCDE-6645-1DDF 1               2345-BCDE-6645-7DDF 6
2345-BCDE-6645-3DDF 2               2345-BCDE-6645-aDDF 7
2345-BCDE-6645-4DDF 3               2345-BCDE-6645-sDDF 8
2345-BCDE-6645-5DDF 4               2345-BCDE-6645-dDDF 9
2345-BCDE-6645-6DDF 5               2345-BCDE-6645-dDDF 10
2345-BCDE-6645-dDDF 11              NULL                NULL
2345-BCDE-6645-dDDF 12              NULL                NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you can manage with the 2 tables Master and detail table.

But due to my curiosity, I am able to solve and give the answer as

```
Declare @table table(id int identity, invoice_id int)

; WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT n = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE n+1 <= 50
)


insert into @table  SELECT n
FROM Numbers

Select (a.id  )%5 ,* from @table a join @table b on a.id+5 = b.id and a.id != b.id

;WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT n = 1, o = 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 10, o = o+10
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE n+1 <= 50
)

select a.id ParentId,a.invoice_id ParentInvoiceId, --b.n, b.o, 
c.invoice_id childInvoiceID from @table a 
join Numbers b on a.id between b.n and b.o
left join @table c on a.id + 5 = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

First i create grps based on whether the in_invoiceid is divisible by 5 or not.(Ignore the remainders)

After that i create a category to indicate between alternative groups(ie by checking if the remainder is 0 or otherise)

Then its a matter of dense_ranking the records on the basis of the category field ordered by in_invoiceid

Lastly a join with category=1 rows with same dense_rank as those records in category=0

```
create table Invoicetable(IN_ID varchar(100), IN_InvoiceID int)


INSERT INTO Invoicetable (IN_ID, IN_InvoiceID)
VALUES
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-1DDF', 1),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-3DDF', 2),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-4DDF', 3),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-5DDF', 4),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-6DDF', 5),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-7DDF', 6),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-aDDF', 7),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-sDDF', 8),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-dDDF', 9),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-dDDF', 10),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-dDDF', 11),
    ('2345-BCDE-6645-dDDF', 12);

with data
  as (
select *
      ,(in_invoiceid-1)/5 as grp
      ,case when ((in_invoiceid-1)/5)%2=0 then '1' else '0' end as category
      ,dense_rank() over(partition by  case when ((in_invoiceid-1)/5)%2=0 then '1' else '0' end
                    order by in_invoiceid) as rnk
  from invoicetable a
      )
   select *
      from data a
 left join data b
        on a.rnk=b.rnk       
       and b.category=0
     where a.category=1
```

Here is db fiddle link.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=287f101737c580ca271940764b2536ae